# Why doesn't a overridden toString() method in java throw a NPE

Tags: java

This might sound funny or baseless to some . Forgive me for that :)

I have overridden a `toString()` method in java to see contents of the object created and it works fine with valid objects created . My doubt is shouldn't it throw a `NullPointerException` when I call the `toString()` method with a null reference .

Below is my code snippet

```
public class Test {

    String name;
    public Test(String naam) {
        name = naam;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    void Display() {
        System.out.println("Display "+ name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test validName = new Test("som");
        System.out.println("toString "+validName);
        validName.Display();

        validName = null;
        System.out.println(validName); // Prints "null" . Why doesnt it throw a NPE ?
        validName.Display(); // throws NPE for obvious reasons :) 
    }

}
```

Comment: You get the same result as printing `System.out.println(null);`

Comment: Where are you calling `toString`?

Comment: On `null` objects `toString` is not called

Answer (score 1):

`println` specially handles nulls. `System.out` is just a static reference of type `PrintStream`, and the docs for [`PrintStream::println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) state:

> This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value ...

Tracing it down, [`String::valueOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-)'s javadoc state:

> **Returns**: if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null" ...